# Noun for "a person who deeply appreciates aesthetics"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun for a person to convey two things: their particularly keen appreciation of aesthetics, and their ability to create aesthetically appealing objects.

For example, Steve Jobs. A man with a famously keen sense of what is beautiful, at every level, be it user interface design, the connectors on cables or the stairs at retail stores.

The closest I've got is "aesthetician", but that conveys more the study of aesthetics, rather than the appreciation and ability to craft aesthetic perfection.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, an "aesthetician" is something like a beautician--I've seen this specifically for people who do eyebrow etc. waxing.

Answer (score 6):

Within a minute of posting I notice a derivation I'd managed to miss that fits my criteria:

> aesthete
>
> 1) a person who has or professes to have refined sensitivity toward the beauties of art or nature.
>
> 2) a person who affects great love of art, music, poetry, etc., and indifference to practical matters.

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aesthete)

Comment: But does aesthete convey:"*their ability to create aesthetically appealing objects.*"? In that case I would suggest, **artist** which covers both points you asked for.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Or *artisan*.